# Powershell execution policy's effect on remote processes

Tags: powershell, smb, service-account

A piece of python code at work was designed to run a few `.ps1` scripts on remote machines to test for weak spots, using impacket.

The flow is -

- We use `impacket`'s `SMBConnection` to upload `.bat` and `.ps1` files to the remote machine.
- `impacket` starts a service on the remote machine using `scmr.hRStartServiceW()`.
- The service launches the `.bat` file.
- The `.bat` file launches the `.ps1` file.
- The results are saved to a local file, and get pulled back using `impacket`.
- This gets repeated for several scripts.

This stops working when the powershell execution policy for `MachinePolicy` is set to `AllSigned`, even though the scripts were signed.

- It seems as though the `.bat` file doesn't get started  - a print to file was added before launching the `.ps1`, and the file is not created.
- If the `.bat` file is run locally when logged to the remote machine, works ok (file with printout created, scripts run and yield results).

We tried to replace the `.bat` file with an `.exe` file, that accepts the `.ps1` file name as a parameter and launches it using with powerhsell. It also prints to a log before that.

Results:

- With `MachinePolicy` set to `ByPass` - the log is generated, the `.ps1` script runs and yield results.
- With `MachinePolicy` set to `AllSigned` - log is generated, script doesn't seem to run.
- With `MachinePolicy` set to `AllSigned` - launching the `.exe` when logged in to the machine via `Remmina`/`RDP`- runs ok as with the `.bat` file (log created, result files from `.ps1` script created).

I'm not sure what the discrepancy is.

It seems that the powershell execution policy somehow affects a remote process' ability to do things.

Can someone shed light on this?